# How to handle and keep image quality of featured image uploads

Tags: post-thumbnails

My idea is to use the uploaded thumbnail/featured image from the post as a image with the height of 750px and 100% width of the page on my page.

Everything is working fine however the image quality is very poor after I set the height to 750px.

My guess is when you upload the thumbnail somehow wordpress decompress the image to a lower quality because they expect it to be used for a small thumbnail.

Is there a way to keep the original image quality when uploaded as a featured image?

When displaying the image I'm attaching a simple class to make sure it has 750px height and 100% width:

```
   the_post_thumbnail( array('class' => ' responsiveThumbnail'));
```

css:

```
   .responsiveThumbnail  {

        width: 100%;
        height: 750px;
        margin: 0;

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Several things could be impacting the image quality, but the biggest impact is calling `the_post_thumbnail()` without giving it a size. By default that will get the "thumbnail" image size, which by default is 150x150 pixels.

Try this instead:

`the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => ' responsiveThumbnail'));`

Then you'll be pulling the full-size image rather than the autogenerated thumbnail.

If you're still not getting the quality you'd like after you confirm you're pulling full-sized images, check:

- Plugins - some image plugins may adjust the image quality. You may want to disable any image-related plugins to see if it makes a difference.
- Core image quality setting - Core itself compresses somewhat by default. You can override this with

```
<?php
add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg){return 100;});
?>
```